# I want to replace list into elements of list

Tags: list, replace, prolog

```
item_replacement_item_mapped(E, Es, E, Es).
item_replacement_item_mapped(X,  _, E, [E]) :-
   dif(X, E).

repl(Es0,X,Xs,Es) :-
   maplist(item_replacement_item_mapped(X,Xs), Es0, Ess1),
   append(Ess1, Es).
```

Example I have list `[a,b,c,d,b,c,e,f]` and I want to replace list  `[x,y,z]` into `[b,c]`. Final results would be `[a,x,y,z,d,x,y,z,e,f]`. How can I write predicate in Prolog?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please [edit] to show your best failed attempt at solving this problem independently.

Comment: Do some searching on this site in the Prolog section. This has been asked and answered at least once before.